# DXA 1.4 JAVA Error serializing field XHTML type

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.4

When creating an entity with an XHTML field, I've got the following error:

```
 org.w3c.dom.ls.LSException: unable-to-serialize-node: unable-to-serialize-node: The node could not be serialized.
    at org.apache.xml.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl.writeToString(DOMSerializerImpl.java:506)
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.DefaultRichTextProcessor.innerXml(DefaultRichTextProcessor.java:101) [dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.DefaultRichTextProcessor.resolveRichText(DefaultRichTextProcessor.java:167) [dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.DefaultRichTextProcessor.processRichText(DefaultRichTextProcessor.java:150) [dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.fields.converters.XhtmlFieldConverter.getFieldValues(XhtmlFieldConverter.java:57) [dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.fields.converters.AbstractFieldConverter.getFieldValue(AbstractFieldConverter.java:23) [dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.SemanticFieldDataProviderImpl.getFieldData(SemanticFieldDataProviderImpl.java:151) [dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl$1.doWith(SemanticMapperImpl.java:123) [dxa-common-impl-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:570) [spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:547) [spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.mapping.SemanticMapperImpl.createEntity(SemanticMapperImpl.java:102) [dxa-common-impl-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.EntityBuilderImpl.createEntity(EntityBuilderImpl.java:298) [dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.mapping.EntityBuilderImpl.createEntity(EntityBuilderImpl.java:278) [dxa-tridion-provider-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

The field value is: Test and I checked that the node build is Test. The code is failing when doing the writeToString function. 
Any clues?

Comment: Are you aware that you are using a pre-release version of DXA 1.5?

Comment: Yes, I know but the funcion is the same in the master release. I would like to know if you have tested to have a rich field without any html content, does it work for you?

Comment: I checked the code with the release 1.7 and it's identical, and we are having the same problem.